# Sorting files based on content using command line

Tags: linux, sorting, command-line, grep

I have a database of files in a folder. I wish to sort the files containing `*C:` into one folder and the files containing `*c:` into another folder. How can this by achieved?**

I can use `*.krn` to access every file.

Comment: What about files that contain *both* `*C:` *and* `*c:` ? Or *neither* ?

Comment: They wont. But in that case they could be left untouched or what is the easiest. I think that if there is a command to extract say "*C:" then I can perform the same command again on the database for "*c:"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ grep --help | grep with-matches
-l, --files-with-matches  print only names of FILEs containing matches
```

What now depends on how many files there are and how paranoid you must be about their names. From the simplest

```
mv $(grep -l pattern files) target
```

to the most robust

```
grep -l -Z pattern files | xargs -0 mv -t target-directory --
```